# $in requires an array as a second argument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to make some aggregations and I have the following problem. I need to use "pipeline" and I'm getting an error when the array I'm looking for is missing.

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'comments',
        let: { comments: '$comments' },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $in: ['$_id', '$$comments']
                    },
                    isDeleted: false
                }
            }
        ],
        as: 'comments'
    }
}
```

With this stage I get the following error:

`'$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing'`

Because not all documents have the field "comments".

Note: I'm using **pipeline** instead of **foreingField** and **localField** because I need to filter with `isDeleted: false` and maybe other matching conditions.

Is there anyway to make this lookup only if the document has the field **comments**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

you can add `$ifNull` or `$and` with not null or exists condition in `$expr`

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'comments',
        let: { comments: '$comments' },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: { 
                        $and: [
                            { $in: ['$_id', { $ifNull: ['$$comments',[]] }] },
                            { $eq: ["$isDeleted", false] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: 'comments'
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if though Compass gives me this error `Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.` executing this from Mongoose it works as expected. Is there any reason why Compass suggests it is incorrect? Any way, many thanks for your reply!

Comment: `isDeleted: false` is outside the `$expr`, that could be the reason

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet, the person that marked as duplicate my question, suggests that I need to add an extra layer on top of my original lookup, $addField to add the comments array if missing. The $expr way with $in and $eq as conditions still gives me the error...

Comment: @AlexandruComanescu Well the above solution also works using `$ifNull`. Now what is the issue? The duplicate answer clearly shows the reason

Comment: Hi @AnthonyWinzlet, sorry if I wasn't clear in my reply. What I meant to say was that your answer (adding `$addField` stage) solved my question. With the `$ifNull` i'm getting this error `Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" ` in Compass aggregations but executing the code on mongoDB shell it works as expected.